# list only folders in a directory

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to get a user to enter a folder name from those listed in a particular directory. The following gives me the list but contains the full path which is likely to confuse the user. My string %officeL% refers to the path location e.g. c:\folder1\folder2\

`for /d %%X in (%officeL%*) do echo %%X`

Ideally I'd like to just get a simple list of just the folders in the final location specified in my string e.g. client1, client2, client3...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use batch parameter modifiers:

```
for /d %%X in (%officeL%*) do echo %%~nX
```

See http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true or

```
for /?
```

for more information.

Comment: +1, though you really should use `%%~nxX` since a folder name can include an extension.

Answer (score 1):

Following will work for you

```
    @Echo OFF
    FOR /F %%G IN ('DIR /b %officeL%') DO CALL :Folders "%%G" 

    EXIT /b

    :Folders
    SET str1=%~1
    Echo %str1%
```

Comment: This is useful but only lists the first folder for my routine, would it need to be looped to get all?